# expression error in Objective-C method call

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

I've dived into learning Objective-C and hit a little snag in when calling a method. Here's my simple code snippets:

**Player.h code snippet:**

```
@interface Player : NSObject{


}

-(void) performAction;
-(int) addNumber:(int) a toNumber:(int) b;

@end
```

**Player.m code snippet:**

```
@implementation Player

-(void)performAction{
    NSLog(@"Here it is!");
}

-(int)addNumber:(int)a toNumber:(int)b{
    return a+b;

}


@end
```

Calling method from main.m:

```
int val = [playerOne addNumber:(int)3 toNumber:(int)3];
```

In the above line of code, i keep getting an 'Expected expression' error.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Comments deleted: not salvageable.

Comment: @failedComputerScientist please provide your main function. I am sure, there must be a syntax error. maybe due to invisible characters. did u copy and paste it?

Comment: you can try to dlete all blanks from the beginning of the line `int val = [playerOne addNumber:(int)3 toNumber:(int)3];` to the end of the line before.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: Will try that. However, imo I find it unnecessary to include the type when calling a method.

Comment: sure. I forgot to remove the casts. they are absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: what I want to say: that error sounds like an syntax error to me. and in copy and pysting it happens often, that unprintable chars are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me.

**Player.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Player : NSObject

- (void)performAction;
- (int)addNumber:(int)a toNumber:(int)b;

@end
```

**Player.m**

```
#import "Player.h"

@implementation Player

- (void)performAction {
    NSLog(@"Here it is!");
}

- (int)addNumber:(int)a toNumber:(int)b {
    return a+b;
}

@end
```

**main.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Player.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Player *playerOne = [Player new];
        int val = [playerOne addNumber:(int)3 toNumber:(int)3];

        NSLog(@"%d", val);


        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats interesting. It only worked for me once I removed the int casting.